# Using a for loop in a bash scrip to iterate over extentions held in a csv file to download data from NASA

Tags: linux, bash, loops, download, satellite

I am currently trying to download data from (https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/search/order). They provide a bash file (https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/tools-and-services/data-download-scripts/) which I need to try and edit. I have a .csv file with all of the file extensions I need to download (specifically I need all VNP46A1 data for China from 2015 until now.

In pseudo-code form I would like to add the following:

```
FOR url_path IN url_list:
recurse "https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/archive/allData/5000/VNP46A1/“+”$url_path"+”.h5" “your_directory”+”$url_path" "TOKEN_HERE"
```

I need to edit this bash to iterate over the files in the csv and download them into a folder for use later.

The bash file is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

function usage {
  echo "Usage:"
  echo "  $0 [options]"
  echo ""
  echo "Description:"
  echo "  This script will recursively download all files if they don't exist"
  echo "  from a LAADS URL and stores them to the specified path"
  echo ""
  echo "Options:"
  echo "    -s|--source [URL]         Recursively download files at [URL]"
  echo "    -d|--destination [path]   Store directory structure to [path]"
  echo "    -t|--token [token]        Use app token [token] to authenticate"
  echo ""
  echo "Dependencies:"
  echo "  Requires 'jq' which is available as a standalone executable from"
  echo "  https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/"
}

function recurse {
  local src=$1
  local dest=$2
  local token=$3

  echo "Querying ${src}.json"

  for dir in $(curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer ${token}" ${src}.json | jq '.[] | select(.size==0) | .name' | tr -d '"')
  do
    echo "Creating ${dest}/${dir}"
    mkdir -p "${dest}/${dir}"
    echo "Recursing ${src}/${dir}/ for ${dest}/${dir}"
    recurse "${src}/${dir}/" "${dest}/${dir}"
  done

  for file in $(curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer ${token}" ${src}.json | jq '.[] | select(.size!=0) | .name' | tr -d '"')
  do
    if [ ! -f ${dest}/${file} ] 
    then
      echo "Downloading $file to ${dest}"
      # replace '-s' with '-#' below for download progress bars
      curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer ${token}" ${src}/${file} -o ${dest}/${file}
    else
      echo "Skipping $file ..."
    fi
  done
}

POSITIONAL=()
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]
do
  key="$1"

  case $key in
    -s|--source)
    src="$2"
    shift # past argument
    shift # past value
    ;;
    -d|--destination)
    dest="$2"
    shift # past argument
    shift # past value
    ;;
    -t|--token)
    token="$2"
    shift # past argument
    shift # past value
    ;;
    *)    # unknown option
    POSITIONAL+=("$1") # save it in an array for later
    shift # past argument
    ;;
  esac
done

if [ -z ${src+x} ]
then 
  echo "Source is not specified"
  usage
  exit 1
fi

if [ -z ${dest+x} ]
then 
  echo "Destination is not specified"
  usage
  exit 1
fi

if [ -z ${token+x} ]
then 
  echo "Token is not specified"
  usage
  exit 1
fi

recurse "$src" "$dest" "$token"
```

and a shortened (for testing purposes) csv file is given as:

```
/archive/allData/5000/VNP46A1/2015/001/VNP46A1.A2015001.h30v05.001.2019135185504.h5
/archive/allData/5000/VNP46A1/2015/002/VNP46A1.A2015002.h30v05.001.2019136091632.h5
/archive/allData/5000/VNP46A1/2015/003/VNP46A1.A2015003.h30v05.001.2019136075625.h5
/archive/allData/5000/VNP46A1/2015/004/VNP46A1.A2015004.h30v05.001.2019136081706.h5
/archive/allData/5000/VNP46A1/2015/005/VNP46A1.A2015005.h30v05.001.2019136084155.h5
/archive/allData/5000/VNP46A1/2015/006/VNP46A1.A2015006.h30v05.001.2019136084128.h5
/archive/allData/5000/VNP46A1/2015/007/VNP46A1.A2015007.h30v05.001.2019136085336.h5
/archive/allData/5000/VNP46A1/2015/008/VNP46A1.A2015008.h30v05.001.2019136103147.h5
/archive/allData/5000/VNP46A1/2015/009/VNP46A1.A2015009.h30v05.001.2019136100110.h5
```

Any help or suggestions will be much appreciated.

Kind regards

Comment: Include a [mcve] in your question. This is too broad

Comment: Unfortunately, they do not provide one of these either which is why I don't know what to do. I will try and write the problem is pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create a bash script that will loop over each line to download the data that you need, using the script provided by NASA.

For example say the below script was a file called save-data.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read p; do
    ./laads-data-download.sh -s $P -d "destination" -t "token"
    echo "$p"
done <paths.txt
```

Example tree structure:

```
nasa-satellite-data
├── laads-data-download.sh
├── paths.txt
└── save-data.sh
```